# Display User's Input in the Form of a List

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create the function `function calculateGroceries()`. The function is supposed to prompt the user for the `itemName` and `itemPrice`. When the user enters `-1`, it displays the `itemTotal` and all `itemName`  and terminates the loop. I am having trouble with having the function displaying all `itemName` into the form of a list. My apologies, I tried but messed up at some point.

```js
     function calculateGroceries(){
        
            const SENTINEL = -1;
           
            let itemName = 0;
            let itemPrice = 0;
            let itemTotal = 0;
            let itemValues =0;


         while ( itemName != SENTINEL){
            itemName = prompt("Enter an item for the grocery list. Enter -1 when finished.");
            itemName = parseFloat(itemName);
            itemPrice = prompt("Enter price of item.");
            itemPrice = parseFloat(itemPrice);


            if (itemName != SENTINEL){
                itemTotal += itemPrice;
                itemValues++;
            }
         }
       

            let li = "<li>" + itemName + "</li>";
            
            document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
            document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = itemTotal;
         }
```

```html
    <h1>Grocery Shopping List </h1>

 

        <form name="myForm" >
            <!--prompts user for items and runs the function-->
             <button type="button" onclick="calculateGroceries();">Click here to enter the grocery list </button>

        <ul id= "list"></ul>
        <div> Total: <span id="total"></span></div>
```

Comment: `let li = "<li>" + itemName + "</vi>";` There is typo with `</vi>` Maybe not the full solution but let's iterate

Comment: why a closing tag `</vi>`? - `let li = "<li>" + itemName + "</vi>";`

Comment: Thanks just corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple problems, `appendChild` expects the element to be a node, not plain text. You randomly refer to `idea` but that doesn't exist in the HTML and you didn't have the appending in the loop. Also you don't want to parseFloat the name of the item as it will most likely be a string.

Looks like you took out the `idea` problem as I was doing this answer.

```js
function calculateGroceries(){
        
            const SENTINEL = -1;
           
            let itemName = 0;
            let itemPrice = 0;
            let itemTotal = 0;
            let itemValues =0;
            let list_el = document.getElementById("list");
            let total_el = document.getElementById("total");

         while ( itemName != SENTINEL){
            itemName = prompt("Enter an item for the grocery list. Enter -1 when finished.");

            itemPrice = prompt("Enter price of item.");
            itemPrice = parseFloat(itemPrice);


            if (itemName != SENTINEL){
                itemTotal += itemPrice;
                itemValues++;
                
                let li = document.createElement("li");
                li.innerHTML = itemName
            
                list_el.appendChild(li);
                total_el.innerHTML = itemTotal;
            }
         }
            
         }
```

```html
<h1>Grocery Shopping List </h1>

 

        <form name="myForm" >
            <!--prompts user for items and runs the function-->
             <button type="button" onclick="calculateGroceries();">Click here to enter the grocery list </button>

        <ul id= "list"></ul>
        <div> Total: <span id="total"></span></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I realized I left that line in there as I was trying solutions and didn't delete all the other stuff I added.